# retrieveing from db using while Rownum works only when rownum = 1

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I'm trying to retrieve data from database based on rownum value,

```
select * from MY_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM = 4
```

it only gives the result when the rownum = 1, otherwise it's empty. Even though I'm sure my table has more rows!

```
              name      age 
--------     --------  -------  
1             Joe       10     
2             Leo       3    
3             Adam      9
```

For example the table above I can only get joe's info, by saying while rownum = 1, the others just give no result

Comment: Is rownum a variable in the table? is it an integer?

Comment: no it is not.........

Comment: i just created a column named row_num that auto increments, works fine now i used it instead of rownum

Comment: [quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) "*Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false*"

Comment: so if i want to retrieve Adams's row only using rownum, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that this is your table:

```
SQL> select * from my_table;

NAME                        AGE
-------------------- ----------
Joe                          10
Leo                           3
Adam                          9
Yura                          1
```

`ROWNUM` can't be used with the "=" sign (Nishant Gupta told you why):

```
SQL> select * from my_table where rownum = 3;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

But, you can use "<=":

```
SQL> select * from my_table where rownum <= 3;

NAME                        AGE
-------------------- ----------
Joe                          10
Leo                           3
Adam                          9

SQL>
```

Or, if you want to use "=" anyway (as you need the 3rd value only), you'll have to use an inline view which selects `ROWNUM` (and alias it, as "RN" - for example) along with `ORDER BY` clause, such as

```
SQL> select name, age
  2  from (select rownum rn, name, age
  3        from my_table
  4        order by age
  5       )
  6  where rn = 3;

NAME                        AGE
-------------------- ----------
Adam                          9

SQL>
```

Or, using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
SQL> select name, age
  2  from (select name, age, row_number() over (order by age) rn
  3        from my_table
  4       )
  5  where rn = 3;

NAME                        AGE
-------------------- ----------
Adam                          9

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ROWNUM` returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle select the row from the table. The first row has `ROWNUM` 1, the second 2 etc.

With a query like

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ROWNUM = 2
```

the first row fetched has `ROWNUM` 1, and makes the where condition false. The next row, the second, is now the first row and has `ROWNUM` 1, and makes the where condition false, etc.

Comment: it doesn't give any result